# How to avoid Serialization for extended class in java

Tags: java

I have Two classes A and B.Class B is Implementing Serializable interface and Class A extends B.So how to avoid serializing Class A.

Comment: Don't write any code to serialize Class A

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of using inheritance. Maybe also create an interface for how you want `B` and `A` objects to act. For example:

```
interface Foo {
    void foo();
}

public class B implements java.io.Serializable, Foo {
    // some instance vars and methods
    public void foo() {
        // b implementation.
    }
}

public class A implements Foo {
    private final B b;
    public A(final B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void foo() {
        b.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was asked in the interview this question so in your solution we cannot extend B but acheive the functionality right?

Comment: Sure it's possible. While by default it would also make `A` serializable, we can still prevent `A` from being serialized. Of course it's preferable to not get into a situation like that. I'll post the solution tomorrow, if you haven't managed to find it yourself by then.